# Is it possible to create an attribute that can only be set in the constructor in Moose?

Tags: perl, moose

Is it possible to create an attribute that can only be set in the constructor in Moose? I’d like to do something like this:

```
my $foo = new Foo(file => 'foo.txt');
my $bar = new Foo(string => $str);
$foo->file('baz.txt'); # dies
```

I know I can create an attribute that can not be set in constructor, but the complementary case seems to be missing.

Comment: BTW, you should really not use the indirect method syntax (Foo->new is preferred to new Foo). See here for an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429657/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isn't that just a read-only attribute? If I write

```
package Foo;
use Moose;

has 'file' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str');
has 'string' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str');

1;
```

then your code dies with

```
Cannot assign a value to a read-only accessor
```