# Is this the equivalent function call to a Perl constructor call?

Tags: perl, oop

I can have a constructor like this :

```
sub create {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self  = {};
  return bless $self,$class;
}
```

and when I create an object, I can write this:

```
my $object = create Object;
```

Is this:

```
my $object = Object::create("Object");
```

the only equivalent to that constructor call?

Comment: You don't have to use `<pre><code>$object</code></pre>` just put four spaces in front of the code block, or better yet just select it, and press **`[Ctrl]`** + **`[K]`** .

Comment: It's a very common convention to use `new` as the name of your constructor.  Yeah, you could call it `chew_toenail_clippings` if you wanted to and it would work, but that's hardly mnemonic (if a bit gross).  Also, you may wish to investigate Moose (http://moose.perl.org/), it is a very powerful OO system for Perl that will save you typing tons of redundant code (see the 'unsweetened' example: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Unsweetened.pod )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the equivalent call is

```
my $object = Object->create();
```

If you use the fully qualified name of the `create` function without the arrow syntax, you aren't going through Perl's OO method dispatch, and therefore any inherited methods will not work.

The arrow syntax is preferred over the "indirect" `create Object` syntax. For the reasons why, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429657/what-is-the-difference-between-new-someclass-and-someclass-new-in-perl/429798#429798).

Comment: could you tell me all the equivalent calls? I don't care about the side effects of each, just the syntax.

Comment: The indirect `new Object` and arrow syntax `Object->new` are equivalent, except for the syntax ambiguity problems I mentioned with the indirect form. The only other way to call a function in another package is with its fully-qualified name, e.g. `Object::new()` which behaves exactly the same as calling `new()` in the current package.