# How can I extract some XML data from a URL using XML::Twig?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I want to get a specific string, for example 123 in <received>123</received> from 
some XML that will be retrieved from a URL.

I have write a code but stuck with an error message:

> Attempt to bless into a reference at /usr/share/perl5/XML/Twig.pm line 392.

How can I solve it?

The code:

```
use XML::Twig;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'http://192.168.1.205:13000/status.xml';
my $twig = new XML::Twig(TwigRoots => {
'smsc/received' => sub {$author = $_[1]->text;  }});
$twig->nparse( $url );
$twig->print;
```

Comment: As a side note, see this answer for why using `new XML::Twig` is bad and why `XML::Twig->new` is preferred: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429657/what-is-the-difference-between-new-someclass-and-someclass-new-in-perl/429798#429798

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I rewrote it with my $twig = XML::Twig->new( Twig_Roots => { ... }}); works well :) –

Answer (score 6, accepted):

nparse takes care of the `new` for you (hence the 'n'), what you want in this case is probably `xparse`, or just let the module figure it out and do this:

```
my $url= 'http://192.168.1.205:13000/status.xml';
my $twig= XML::Twig->parse( twig_roots => 
                              { 'smsc/received' => sub { $author= $_[1]->text;}},
                             $url
                           );
$twig->print; # I am not sure why you print the twig instead of just $author
```

Comment: Thanks mirod. It works well with xparse. FYI, the $twig->print is just for debugging use. Actually I just want value $author.

Answer (score 3):

Appears to be a bug in *nparse* method because if you replace that line with:

```
$twig->parse( LWP::Simple::get($url) );
```

Then you should find it works fine (or it does when I try it).

/I3az/

Comment: it's not a bug in nparse, it's a bug in the way it's called ;--)

Comment: Ah yes... I can see it explicitly in your POD now!  Retested my example here and it works brilliantly now:  my $twig = XML::Twig->nparse( twig_handlers => {
    title => sub { print $_->text },
}, 'http://w3c.org');

Comment: in fact nparse and xparse were kinda failed experiments, which eventually lead me to the simple rewriting of parse to take care of everything for you (new _and_ determining the kind of parse to use)

Comment: @mirod:  Let me take this gushy moment to say a sincere "thank you" for XML::Twig.  Its been a enjoyable, powerful and sometimes life saving tool over the years.  Yours Barry

Comment: PS.  Thats "life saving" in terms of getting the work out despite the other $work issues ;-)

Comment: Tried thed code before however it seems fail to work with TwigRoots.

Comment: I was just commenting on nparse bit to get you past that hurdle.  I noticed there was other things in your code that needs addressing...  Mirod's answer covers these.