# How can I specify which port to use in Perl's IO::Socket::INET?

Tags: perl, inet

I am using [IO::Socket::INET](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket/INET.html) to create inter-process communication in my program. I need to use a specific port number in my TCP client. I was following the example in Perl doc, but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

old code(working):

```
tx_socket = new IO::Socket::INET->new('127.0.0.1:8001') || die "Can't connect to 127.0.0.1:8001 : $!\n";
```

new code(not working):

```
tx_socket = new IO::Socket::INET->new('127.0.0.1:8001', LocalPort=>9000 ) || die "Can't connect to 127.0.0.1:8001 : $!\n";
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Why are you calling `new` twice on the same object? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429657/what-is-the-difference-between-new-someclass-and-someclass-new-in-perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grant McLean's answer works, if you fix the missing comma, but "works" here may be relative to what you are expecting.

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
$sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(
    PeerAddr  => '127.0.0.1',
    PeerPort  => 8001,
    LocalPort => 9000,
    Proto     => 'tcp'
);
die("No socket!\n") unless $sock;
print "Socket good!\n";
```

Running this yields:

```
No socket!
```

Which isn't because the code doesn't work, it's working as expected (in my case).  That is, it's expected that a connection to a localhost port 8001 will fail with nothing listening on the other side.  This illustrates the usefulness of error reporting:

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
$sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(
    PeerAddr  => '127.0.0.1',
    PeerPort  => 8001,
    LocalPort => 9000,
    Proto     => 'tcp'
) or die("$!\n");
die("No socket!\n") unless $sock;
print "Socket good!\n";
```

Which running now yields:

```
Connection refused
```

If I run netcat listening on port 8001, I get a different result:

```
Socket good!
```

Comment: Thanks kbenson and Grant, it is working now by using the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket/INET.html), you should be doing something like:

```
$sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(
    PeerAddr  => '127.0.0.1',
    PeerPort  => 8001,
    LocalPort => 9000,
    Proto     => 'tcp'
) or die "Connect error: $!";
```

Comment: I tried this format also, the INET function call does not return a valid socket. I called $sock->print after the code, Perl complains about $sock is an undefined value.

Comment: If the new method returns undef then you should look for an error message in $!.  I've added the error check above.