# Why can't Perl find File::BaseName->fileparse?

Tags: macos, perl

On OS X 10.8.4, in a test perl program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use File::BaseName;

my $fname = "/usr/local/junk.txt";
my ($name, $path, $suffix1) = File::BaseName->fileparse($fname, qr'\.[^\.]*');
```

Any ideas why I get the error message:

```
Can't locate object method "fileparse" via package "File::BaseName"
(perhaps you forgot to load "File::BaseName"?)
```

For that matter, why do I need to put `File::BaseName`? If I don't, it says

```
Undefined subroutine &main::fileparse
```

perl -v gives:

> This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 4 (v5.12.4) built for
>   darwin-thread-multi-2level
>
> And @INC includes /System/Library/Perl/5.12/ and
>   /System/Library/Perl/5.12/File/BaseName.pm exists and has fileparse in
>   it.

In case it helps, when I Use `File::Spec` and refer to `File::Spec->splitpath`, that works fine (but I do have to put the full line).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl Module Method Calls: Can't call method "X" on an undefined value at ${SOMEFILE} line ${SOMELINE}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597605/perl-module-method-calls-cant-call-method-x-on-an-undefined-value-at-somef)

Comment: PBP: use slashes or curly braces for regex: `qr{ \. [^\.]* \z }msx`

Comment: It's not the duplicate of the problem Barmar linked to, don't vote to close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's case sensitivity: 
[`Basename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) is written with lowercase letter "N". [Acme::require::case](http://p3rl.org/Acme%3a%3arequire%3a%3acase) will prevent that problem.

Besides, you don't have to use a qualified name for `fileparse` after you've imported the `File::Basename` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Basename; # !!!

my $fname = "/usr/local/junk.txt";
my ($name, $path, $suffix1) = fileparse($fname, qr'\.[^\.]*'); # !!!
```

Comment: he also wasn't using the correct syntax for the qualified name. It's `::`, not `->`.

Comment: That was exactly it.  Thank you. It's amazing how long one can stare at something and not see it. Being a perl novice, on would think it would have complained on the use statement when it didn't find the file. The Acme reference is quite useful also to prevent this during development.

Comment: @mackworth: "how long one can stare at something and not see it" - I think everyone experienced this phenomenon - you can't find a simple mistake in your own code, while you would easily see the same mistake in someone else's code. A possible reason is that you know your own code too good and don't read it very carefully... You are welcome!