# How to require a file and use its subroutine

Tags: perl

how can I use a subroutine in a required file, when the subroutien has to get variables:

file.pl:

```
...
sub func{
  my ($var) = @_;
  ..

}
```

main.pl:

```
..
require "file.pl";
func(1);
..
```

this is not working for me, I'm getting an error says `Undefined subroutine &main::func` ..

Comment: `file.pl` should end with true value, ie. `1;`

Comment: I can see only what you post. Ok, did you check path to required file? Are any packages in `file.pl`?

Comment: file.pl use packages, but no package defined in it.

Comment: copy/paste first `package` line above `func()`

Comment: Is `file.pl` also required in other packages that `main.pl` used?

Comment: This answer might help explain what is going on -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597605/perl-module-method-calls-cant-call-method-x-on-an-undefined-value-at-somef/3598353#3598353

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl was telling you that no `main::func` exists (`main` is default package), so
you need to prefix your function with qualified package name,

```
require "file.pl";
Naming::func(1);
```