# Using my() changes XML::Bare behavior drastically

Tags: xml, perl

When I run this Perl script:

```
#!/bin/perl 
use XML::Bare; 
$ob = new XML::Bare(text=>'<xml><name>Bob</name></xml>'); 
for $i (keys %{$ob->{xml}}) {print "KEY: $i\n";}
```

I get no output. However, if I put `$ob` inside a `my()`:

```
#!/bin/perl 
use XML::Bare; 
my($ob) = new XML::Bare(text=>'<xml><name>Bob</name></xml>'); 
for $i (keys %{$ob->{xml}}) {print "KEY: $i\n";}
```

I get this output:

```
KEY: _z 
KEY: _i 
KEY: xml 
KEY: _pos
```

Why does `my()` change this behavior so drastically, especially given 
that I'm at the top level where `my()` should have no effect at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you should always begin your Perl scripts with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

This will force you to declare all your variables with `my` which catches many typos and simple mistakes.

In your case, it's not actually the `my` that causes the changed behavior, but the parentheses, which put `$ob` in list context.

Looking at the [source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/NIGELM/XML-Bare-0.47/lib/XML/Bare.pm) of XML::Bare, we find this in the constructor:

```
sub new { 
    ...
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self if ( !wantarray );
    return ( $self, $self->parse() );
}
```

Notice that the second `return` line calls `->parse` on the new object for you, which you forgot to do in your first example, which is why that one didn't have any data in it.

So you can say

```
my $obj = XML::Bare->new(text=>'<xml><name>Bob</name></xml>'); # in scalar context
$obj->parse;
```

Or

```
my ( $obj ) = XML::Bare->new(text=>'<xml><name>Bob</name></xml>'); # in list context
```

and they should be equivalent.

This is a pretty strange interface choice, but I'm not familiar with `XML::Bare`.

Notice also that I've avoided indirect method syntax (`XML::Bare->new` instead of `new XML::Bare`). This helps to avoid some [nasty problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429657/what-is-the-difference-between-new-someclass-and-someclass-new-in-perl).

Comment: Thanks! I was using parse() earlier, but became surprised when my() appeared to do an automatic parse. I keep incorrectly thinking that "my $foo" is equivalent to "my($foo)".

Comment: `my ($foo)` is equivalent to `(my $foo)`, and `(...) =` tells Perl to use a list assignment operator instead of a scalar assignment operator. See [Mini-Tutorial: Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129)

Answer (score 1):

The XML::Bare module is intentionally designed to work in 2 different ways.

Way #1:

```
my $ob = XML::Bare->new( text => "<xml/>" );
my $tree = $ob->parse();
```

Way #2:

```
my ( $ob, $tree ) = XML::Bare->new( text => "<xml/>" );
```

You are using the module in an undocumented way #3:

```
my ( $ob ) = XML::Bare->new( text => "<xml/>" );
my $tree = $ob->{'xml'};
```

This third way happens to work, because the module stores the tree within it's own object. I would recommend avoiding using it in this way, because it is confusing, and may change in future versions of the module.