# Using Perl FileHandle with a scalar containing string instead of filename

Tags: perl, filehandle

My script download a plain text file using from the internet using LWP::Simple's get() function.

I'd the like to process this string in a filehandle way.  I found this 'elegant' (well, I like it) way of doing this from http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=745018 .

```
my $filelike = get($url); # whole text file sucked up in single string
open my $fh, '<', \$filelike or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
    # do wildly exciting stuff;
};
```

But I like using FileHandle; however, I've not found a way of doing the above using it. So:

```
my $filelike = get($url);
my $fh = new FileHandle \$filelike; # does not work
my $fh = new FileHandle $filelike; # does not work either
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileHandle provides an `fdopen` method which can give you a FileHandle object from a  symbol reference. You can open a raw filehandle to the scalar ref and then wrap that in a FileHandle object.

```
open my $string_fh, '<', \$filelike;
my $fh = FileHandle->new->fdopen( $string_fh, 'r' );
```

(Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/429798/20745) for why you should use `Class->new` instead of the indirect `new Class` notation.)

Comment: Actually, playing around a bit more, I have got it to work.
I used this from the FileHandle doc:  
"If FileHandle::open receives a Perl mode string (">", "+<", etc.) or a POSIX fopen() mode string ("w", "r+", etc.), it uses the basic Perl open operator."  So
`my $filelike = get($url);
my $fh = new FileHandle \$filelike, 'r' or die $!;`
works fine.

Or, taking into account @friedo's advice (thanks for that):

`my $fh = FileHandle->new(\$filelike, 'r') or die $!;`

Comment: Hmmm.. The code friedo posted shouldn't work. The handle in `$string_fh` doesn't have an fd to open.

Comment: Seems to work on 5.20 anyway: `perl -MFileHandle -E 'open my $string_fh, "<", \"some stuff"; my $fh = FileHandle->new->fdopen( $string_fh, "r" ); say $fh->getline'`

Comment: Yes, it *does* work, but it *shouldn't*. As a result, I don't trust it. Besides, creating two file handles is silly and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize that all file handles are objects of the IO::Handle? If all you want is to use the file handle as an object, you don't have to do anything at all.

```
$ perl -e'
    open my $fh, "<", \"abcdef\n";
    STDOUT->print($fh->getline());
'
abcdef
```

Note: In older versions of Perl, you will need to add `use IO::Handle;`.